# Fire and forget messaging with actors?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Service Fabric's actor model is only supporting "request-reply" style communication as far as I can tell. Is there any way I can achieve "fire-and-forget" style communication? (Eg: Like the "ask" vs "tell" messaging in Akka?)

I've ran into this blog post (http://mikhail.io/2016/01/fire-and-forget-in-service-fabric-actors/), but am unsure if this will have any negative consequences or if there is a recommended way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

Have an initialize method on your actor that seeds whatever is required for your task. Setup a timer and return from the initialize method. When the timer fires, shut down the timer, and run your logic Fire and Forget with the guarantee that your work is performed. Rough sample below.

```
public class SomeActor : Actor, ISomeActor
{
    private IActorTimer _sendTimer;

    protected override async Task OnActivateAsync()
    {
        await base.OnActivateAsync();
    }

    protected override async Task OnDeactivateAsync()
    {
        await this.ExecuteAgents();
        await base.OnDeactivateAsync();
    }

    public Task Initialize()
    {
        if (_sendTimer == null)
        {
            //setup timer
            _sendTimer = this.RegisterTimer((obj) =>
            {
                return this.Execute();
            },
                null,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }
    }

    private async Task ExecuteAgents()
    {
        this.UnegisterTimer(_sendTimer);

        //Perform workload
    }
}
```

Comment: Say that Initialize now takes a string as a parameter, and multiple actors will call this actor. Then upon receiving multiple calls to the same actor would we need to track multiple timers for each call made? (If I'm understanding this correctly)

Comment: That depends on what behavior you want. One way is to use randomly generated Ids so that you get a fresh actor instance each time (checking for collisions by seeing if the _sendTimer is null). You can also setup a queue based implementation instead of handling collisions, where when a collision occurs, the specific actor instance is simply doing two pieces of work when the time fires.

Comment: This diagram from the SF docs explains a lot. Just swap client, for a diff actor service. 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/PeuKY.png